# How find relationships with lags and leas in Microsoft project with vba?

Tags: vba, project, ms-project

I have tried to find leads with the Microsoft project VBA but I was not successful I tried the following code but it gives me 2280 leads while the total number of relations in my schedule is 2156

```
Sub NumberofLeads()

Dim Lead As Integer
Dim t As Task
Dim td As TaskDependency


Lead = 0


For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
      
        
        For Each td In t.TaskDependencies  'looping in all the relations of a task
              If td.Lag < 0 Then
                  Lead = Lead + 1
              End If
        Next
      
         
         
    End If
Next t


MsgBox Lead & " Leads exist."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each [task dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependency) consists of two tasks so looping through the tasks and then through all of each task's dependencies will encounter each dependency twice. The best way to handle this is to only look at the dependencies where the task is the predecessor (or successor, just pick one), by checking the [From](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependency.from) (or [To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependency.to)) object's Unique ID and compare it to the current task:

```
Sub NumberofLeads()

Dim Lead As Integer
Dim t As Task
Dim td As TaskDependency

Lead = 0

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        For Each td In t.TaskDependencies
            If td.From.UniqueID = t.UniqueID And td.Lag < 0 Then
                Lead = Lead + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next t

MsgBox Lead & " Leads exist."

End Sub
```

Note: In case dividing by two seems easier than this solution, consider the case of external links. In that case the dependency will only be encountered once (the second task is not in the `ActiveProject.Tasks` collection) so dividing by two would yield the wrong answer.